# OverlappingFileLockException in logback

Tags: logback

I'm hitting the following `OverlappingFileLockException` in LogBack. Is there any know issues with `prudent` mode in this version of Logback?

- `logback-classic 1.0.7`
- `logback-core 1.0.7`
- `slf4j-api 1.7.2`
- `slf4j-ext 1.7.2`

> 11:16:59,252 |-ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE_LOG] - Appender
>   [FILE_LOG] failed to append.
>   java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
>               at java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
>               at      at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
>               at      at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
>               at      at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:972)
>               at      at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.lock(FileChannel.java:1052)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.safeWrite(FileAppender.java:187)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.writeOut(FileAppender.java:204)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:212)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:148)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:103)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:280)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:267)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:449)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:403)
>               at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:803)
>               at      at org.slf4j.ext.LoggerWrapper.info(LoggerWrapper.java:490)

```
<appender name="FILE_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>C:/MyLog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}  [%-20.20(%thread)]  %-6level  %-30.30logger{0} - [%-12.12(S:%mdc{pucid}]) %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: Raised JIRA http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-864

Answer (score 1):

On http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-864 Mahesh Chimanpure says: "`timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy can not be used in prudent mode.`"